# Javascriptのプロパティ名に「-」が有ると正常にコードが実行できない

Tags: javascript, html

以下のコードをブラウザーのコンソールで実行しようとしたところ、-で区切られて認識されてしまい、正常にコードが実行できませんでした。対策方法を知りたいのですが、教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
document.example-form-name.submit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ブラケット表記法](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98%E6%B3%95) を使います。

```js
document["example-form-name"].submit()
```

一般に、プロパティ名が有効な JavaScript の識別子でない場合は、こうします。